# "android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" the permission question

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to know whether a program has the permission "android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"? I used:

```
context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS");
```

but it always returns 0 no matter if I have the permission.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#PERMISSION_GRANTED

Depending on the reference 0 means that the permission has been granted. So it's good ;-)